# Searching for filenames in blob using a wildcard

Tags: azure, powershell, blob, azure-storage, wildcard

I am trying to find any file whose name begins with 'filename', but I cant work it out.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $Context -Container $SourceContainer |
  Get-ChildItem Where{$_.Name -like 'filename'}
```

Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the command below, it works on my side.

```
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $Context -Container $SourceContainer |
  Where-Object {$_.Name -like "filename*"}
```

Test result with no filter and filter:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Joy, that worked. mklement0 for some reason, your options kept looking locally(?). If I want to copy multiple files, like in your example Joy, do I have to write a Foreach because more than one file is listed?

Comment: Ok, after a quick test, I realise now that I do.

Comment: @DrDuran It seems you do not have to write a foreach, you could try `$blobs | Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -Context $sourceContext -DestContext $destinationContext -DestContainer $DestinationContainerName`, the `$blobs` is the result of `Get-AzureStorageBlob`.

Comment: Is there an equivalent way to do this using Azure.Storage.Blobs in c#.  The only option I see to perform server side filtering when using the BlobServiceClient is a prefix (starts with).